# Movie about a group of teens during an alien invasion of some kind

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I had memories of a movie I saw when I was younger about a group of teens (maybe 3 or 4 if I am not mistaken) during an alien invasion. I can't quite remember what time this took place in, but the movie was full color and if I remember right it wasn't very futuristic. I remember the group of teens going off somewhere and staying in a cabin or some small house during the movie. It started off I believe with the teens at a camp of some king before the invasion took place. They were sent to the camp possibly and then that all happened.

I can remember the song 'ain't no mountain high enough' being featured in there when one of the kids was missing his mother he was singing it because it was their special song for if he ever felt lonely.

Comment: What year was this in?

Comment: @DavidW I want to say 2015 or 2016-2017, although I am not completely sure. I added an edit that I just remembered that may have some more info.

Comment: Ironically enough, *Chicken Little* would probably fit the bill other than that you probably would have mentioned that they were all anthropomorphic animals in 3D animation.

Comment: It was a live-action film and the creatures (aliens) reminded me of Demogorgon from Stranger Things. Just a reminder though; not exact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Rim of the World*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8179388/) (2019).

> Four misfit campers must band together and conquer their fears in
> order to save the world during an alien invasion.

The '*Ain't No Mountain High Enough'* scene is below.

Comment: Yes, this was it! I often have little memories of old movies I saw, but I guess this one wasn't as long ago as I thought.

Comment: R/beatmetoit       in all seriousness, i loved this movie, espacially seeing the F22 doing a strafing run